# Is there a replacement for actor yet?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I find [actor](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/actor.html) to be extremely convenient for sequential execution of background work and safe private state. Unfortunately, it is marked as obsolete and has been for some time. I can't find any information on a replacement, though there have been many flow additions to Kotlin Coroutines.

Is there a way to achieve the same benefits as actor with the new coroutine library additions as of today? Would would code that achieves this look like?

Comment: The last news on it that I could find: https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/nm2eaf/kotlin_team_ama_3_ask_us_anything/gznacew/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf&context=3

Comment: 2023, still no news ):